# How to design within a resolution range

Tags: css

I would like to know if it is possible to design a site with a minimum resolution of 1024x768 and have it grow no larger than 1300x800.

I'm not real CSS savoy but I thought that I could do this using `min-width` and `max-width` and that the site would stay between those numbers but that doesn't work.

Is this possible? I don't think I'm after responsive design because I am not designing for any mobile devices. I just need to target a wide range of wide screen monitors.

The issue I see here is that if I design a static resolution of 1024x768 and someone with a monitor and card capable of 1920×1080, it's not going to look very good. I'd like the site to expand and shrink a bit with the user's screen.

This is what I currently have. I have a header and two inline divs below it.

```
#header {
position:relative;
float:left;
width:100%;
background:url(header.jpg) no-repeat #fff;
height:100px;
margin-bottom:5px
}

#wrapper {
height:100%;
width:98.5%;
min-width:1240px;
margin:0 auto
}

#grid-left {
width:45%;
float:left
}

#grid-right {
width:54%;
float:right
}
```

The width of 1240px is too large for a lot of monitors as I'm finding out.

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify, what I am looking for is a design that will start out at 1024px x 768px and grow to a maximum resolution of 1920×1080 but no more than that.

Comment: What did you try? (post your code) What happened? What did you expect to happen? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Seems to work for me? http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/CNaW9/

Comment: what is the question right now?

Comment: @davidpauljunior, David, I think my code will start at 1240px but if I wanted it to stop growing at 1500px, it's not doing that. It will continue to grow.

Comment: On your CSS you haven't specified the `max-width: 1500px` on the `#wrapper`.  My screen isn't as big as 1500px, but testing on lower values worked on my first fiddle.  You can try this on a bigger screen if you like: http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/CNaW9/1/

Comment: @davidpauljunior, David, I just tried it and it's doing the same thing. I edited your fiddle and ran the new code with a new `min-width` of 300px and a `max-width` of 400px. The wrapper never changes size when I resize the window. Am i missing something?

Comment: @NaN, what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Firefox. v22 I think. The most recent one

Comment: @davidpauljunior, doesn't there have to be a float on that element for it to work?

Comment: @NaN you shouldn't need float.  I've just tested in FF v24 and it's working.

Comment: Let me try your fiddle again. I mean, unless I'm so dense that I don't see it. brb

Comment: Yes David, it does seem to be working. Thank you. If you'd like to put this as the answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39799/discussion-between-davidpauljunior-and-nan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your CSS you haven't actually specified the `max-width: 1500px` on the #wrapper.

Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/CNaW9/

Answer (score 0):

You can just use width rather than min-width and max-width with your parent container and you can use

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 1024px) 
and (max-device-width : 1380px) 
{
    #wrapper {
      height:100%;
      min-width:1240px;
      margin:0 auto
    }
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 1400px)  
{
    #wrapper {
      height:100%;
      min-width:1300px;
      margin:0 auto
    }
}
```